# Java socket timeout issue causing too many open files

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io

I have a java socket that has been running for sometime. Today I noticed a lot of socket connection made but then after a few hours I got too many open files. I have set the **timeout** but somehow it did not timeout I don't know why. Below is snippet of my code. In my code I notice in the logs the connection is made and stops at this line-

```
System.out.println("\n\n Trying establish a new db connection ");
dbconn1 = connectionPool.getConnection();
```

Possibly it does not get the connection from pool but there is no error or any socket connection timeout. Is there any solution for this?

```
      private Socket receivedSocketConn1;
ConnectionHandler(Socket receivedSocketConn1) {
  this.receivedSocketConn1=receivedSocketConn1;
}
BufferedWriter writer1 = null; 
 Connection dbconn1 = null;     
     public void run() { // etc
     writer1 = null;
     String message="";
     BufferedReader reader1 = null; 
     try { 

         writer1 =  new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(receivedSocketConn1.getOutputStream()));
         reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(receivedSocketConn1.getInputStream()));
         receivedSocketConn1.setSoTimeout(60000);
         int nextChar=0;
         while ((nextChar=reader1.read()) != -1) {    
             message += (char) nextChar; 
             if (nextChar == '*'){

                 try{   
                    System.out.println("\n\n Trying establish a new db connection ");
                    dbconn1 = connectionPool.getConnection();
                    dbconn1.setAutoCommit(false);
                    System.out.println("\n\n Checking db connection status "+dbconn1.isClosed());
                    if ((dbconn1 == null) || dbconn1.isClosed()) {
                         System.out.println("\n\n db connection status is closed");
                         dbconn1 = connectionPool.getConnection();
                         dbconn1.setAutoCommit(false);
//other codes follow here.
                    }
                 }
                 catch (SQLException ex){ 
                   System.out.println("Error SQL Exception : "+ex.toString());
                   ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                   try{    
                     dbconn1.rollback();  
                   } 
                    catch (Exception rollback) {    
                     System.out.println("\nRollback dbconn1 :");  
                     rollback.printStackTrace(System.out);
                   }
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                   System.out.println("\nSQL Error here :");
                   e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                  try{    
                   dbconn1.rollback();  
                  } 
                  catch (Exception rollback) {    
                    System.out.println("\nRollback dbconn1 :");  
                    rollback.printStackTrace(System.out);
                  }
                }
                finally{
                   try {

                   if ( dbconn1 != null ) {
                     dbconn1.close();
                     System.out.println("\n\n dbConn1 is being closed");
                  }

                  }
                 catch(SQLException ex){
                   System.out.println("SQLException has been caught for dbConn1 close");
                   ex.printStackTrace();
               }               
             } 

           }
       }


      }
      catch (SocketTimeoutException ex){ 
           System.out.println("SocketTimeoutException has been caught ");
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }  
      catch (IOException ex) { 
           System.out.println("IOException has been caught ");
           ex.printStackTrace();
      }  
      catch (Exception ex) { 

           System.out.println("Exception has been caught");
           ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
      }      
      finally{

        try {
            if (writer1 != null ) {
                writer1.close();
            }               
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
           System.out.println("IOException has been caught for finally");
           ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
      }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
  // setup the connection pool
        BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****"); // jdbc url specific to your database, eg jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/yourdb
        config.setUsername("***"); 
        config.setPassword("***");      
        config.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(5);
        config.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(40);
        config.setPartitionCount(1);
        connectionPool = new BoneCP(config); // setup the connection pool           
  }
  catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
  try 
  {
           final ServerSocket serverSocketConn = new ServerSocket(8888);                
           while (true) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                            Socket socketConn1 = serverSocketConn.accept();
                            new Thread(new ConnectionHandler(socketConn1)).start();                     
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Socket Accepting has been caught);
                        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
                }
  } 
  catch (Exception e) 
  {
     System.out.println("Socket Conn has been caught );
     e.printStackTrace(System.out);

  }
}
```

Comment: try closing the BufferedReader/Writer to

Comment: Yes I have tried my issue is that why the time out did not get triggered?

Comment: What kind of Socket are you using where do you work with the Socket I cant find it in your code

Comment: Not a good idea to use sockets and database in this fashion, its very error-prone and hard to maintain. Use some framework or Rest template or something.

Comment: Hi zion I have add the main function where I create the database pool and also shown how I accept the connection n there process them.

Comment: OIK now suppose you format and indent this mess properly so it is legible.

Comment: @EJP yes done with the indent.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the socket timeout.

You're leaking *database* connections. You're getting a connection from the pool and never returning it.

NB Any connection pool that returns null or a closed connection has something ***seriously*** wrong with it. You don't need that test or the following code.

Comment: sorry I have updated code snippet where in my codes I have the try and catch when I create each new connection and finally block I do close it. I have added those code which I did not include earlier to keep the codes short.

Comment: So I am very sure I am closing the connection each time at the end.

Comment: Well what do you expect? I can only comment on the code you posted. My NB remains true.

Comment: sorry for the missing part. Since I am closing the db connection in a proper manner.What else could be causing the issue of too many open files?

Comment: But if the pool is exhausted there should be some error message caught or generated but I never see any I keep getting the socket connected and pause that the line System.out.println("\n\n Trying establish a new db connection "); I mention in my question.

Comment: so are you suggesting anything on the pooling is wrong?